# android proguard fail with mail sending

Tags: android, proguard

I have a project in Eclipse on Windows with a list of services and btoadcastreceivers... It works fine! Now, I have Decided to Proguard it... So, I have added to *project.properties* such lines...

```
target=android-8
proguard.config=C:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\tools\\proguard\\proguard-android.txt
```

And I have *proguard-android.txt* ...

```
    # This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
    # http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-libraryjars C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/**,javax/security/**,javax/activation/**)
# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
# Note that if you want to enable optimization, you cannot just
# include optimization flags in your own project configuration file;
# instead you will need to point to the
# "proguard-android-optimize.txt" file instead of this one from your
# project.properties file.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class com.google.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

# keep setters in Views so that animations can still work.
# see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#beans
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
   void set*(***);
   *** get*();
}

# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

# For enumeration classes, see         http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**
```

I had 247 errors before added line   ###-libraryjars C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/**,javax/security/**,javax/activation/**) ### TO *proguard-android.txt*.... After this modify there no errors. Projects by Export with key makes..... But the application doesn't works fully... More precisely, statistics is not sent to mail... Every time it must send - the app doesn't send... Just place it on sd as should... Could you help??? What is the matter?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified **project.propertis** to ...

```
target=android-8
#proguard.config=C:\\Program Files\\Android\\android-sdk\\tools\\proguard\\proguard-android.txt
progurd.config=proguardbest.cfg
```

And added **proguardbest.cfg** to my project with...

```
-optimizationpasses 5
#When not preverifing in a case-insensitive filing system, such as Windows. Because this tool unpacks your processed jars, you should then use:
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
#Specifies not to ignore non-public library classes. As of version 4.5, this is the default setting
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-libraryjars C:\Program     Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar(java/**,javax/security/**,javax/activation/**)
#Preverification is irrelevant for the dex compiler and the Dalvik VM, so we can switch it off with the -dontpreverify option.
-dontpreverify
#Specifies to write out some more information during processing. If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.
-verbose
#The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and     1.5 can't handle. Note that the Dalvik VM also can't handle aggressive overloading (of     static fields).
#To understand or change this check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/optimizations.html
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
#To repackage classes on a single package
#-repackageclasses ''
#Uncomment if using annotations to keep them.
#-keepattributes *Annotation*
#Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static *** d(...);
public static *** v(...);
}
#To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
# Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
#-keepclassmembers class * {
# public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
#}
#Maintain java native methods 
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}
#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML.
#Uncomment if having any problem with the approach below
-keep public class custom.components.package.and.name.**

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:    
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
public void *(android.view.View);
public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
 }
 -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
#Maintain enums
-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
#To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
 -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
public static <fields>;
}

#Uncomment if using Serializable 
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
java.lang.Object writeReplace();
java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```